# How do I use okhttp in the spring cloud ribbon

Tags: spring, okhttp, netflix-ribbon, spring-cloud-square

The getting started of the spring cloud ribbon is very easy and simple, and it is using the rest template to communicate with backend servers.

But in our project we are more like to use okhttp to do the http request, does anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the [spring-cloud-square](https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-square) project which supplies integration with Square's OkHttpClient and Netflix Ribbon via Spring Cloud Netflix, on the Github. Let's see a test method in the [OkHttpRibbonInterceptorTests.java class](https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-square/blob/master/spring-cloud-square-okhttp/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/square/okhttp/OkHttpRibbonInterceptorTests.java)

```
@Test
@SneakyThrows
public void httpClientWorks() {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            // here you use a service id, or virtual hostname
            // rather than an actual host:port, ribbon will
            // resolve it
            .url("http://" + SERVICE_ID + "/hello")
            .build();
    Response response = builder.build().newCall(request).execute();
    Hello hello = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.body().byteStream(), Hello.class);
    assertThat("response was wrong", hello.getValue(), is(equalTo("hello okhttp")));
}
```